# localStorage.setItem("", ""); not working

Tags: html, local-storage

I am trying to use HTML5 local storage. I fill in the input fields and click the "store" button. Then I reload the page and the input fields are cleared. I then click the "retrieve" button expecting the P1 input field to be filled from local storage. But the field remains blank. What is my mistake?

```
<button onclick="store()" >STORE</button>
<button onclick="retrieve()" >RETRIEVE</button> <br />

<input type = "text" id = "P1"><br />

<script>

function store()
{

localStorage.setItem("S1", "P1");

}

</script>


<script>

function retrieve()
{   

document.getElementById("P1").value= localStorage.getItem("S1");
}

</script>
```

Comment: maybe  `localStorage.getItem("S");` ?

Comment: I fixed it. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Your current code saves a string literal in the localStorage, did you, perhaps, meant `document.getElementById("P1").innerHTML` instead? Also, note that some browsers don't provide localStorage if you load page using `file` protocol, Microsoft Edge, for example.

Comment: Uhhh no. document.getElementById("P1").innerHTML is also a literal.

Comment: your code works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to save value of the input to localstorage you should get the value from id and then pass it as a second parameter to `setItem`:

```
localStorage.setItem("S1", document.getElementById("P1").value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Html tag: input, textarea = use "value", not "innerHTML".

```
document.getElementById("P1").value= localStorage.getItem("S1");
```

Comment: This just displays "P1" in the input field on "retrieve()".

Comment: @verlager which is exactly what you are storing